# Is there a html video player that allows to set authentication headers?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to play a WebM or a mp4 video file using HTML5 video from server that needs token based authentication.
I cannot find any player that will support setting HTTP request headers fr requests that fetch media.

There is support for setting headers only for HLS and DASH media.

Already tried video.js: (https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/6348), react-player, video-react with no luck.

I have implemented desired solution from scratch fetching it by XMLHttpRequest using MediaSource and reding file as Array Buffer (similar to https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html) but I would rather use some existing more robust solution.

Comment: Would up-vote this, as it seems like it could be a good solution https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/1312

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hack, but you could try using a [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker).

It would be possible for your ServiceWorker to attach the appropriate authentication headers, and then you don't have to do anything special or weird in your video player at all.  You can continue to use a standard `<video>` tag.  Additionally, the browser gets to keep its own behavior for what ranges to request, and you won't have to go through the headaches and incompatibilities of Media Source Extensions.

See also:  https://serviceworke.rs/strategy-cache-and-update.html

Note though that this isn't always going to work... there are times when that Service Worker isn't loaded (such as when the user does a shift+refresh).